# How to use Google Vision API in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-vision

I have a list of image URLs in a Google Spreadsheet. I would like to call Google Vision API for each of the URLs and output the response in sheets.

So far i have looked at the tutorial Below:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/getting-started-with-the-google-vision-api-from-gsuite

However, the above utilises HTML output.
Is there a simple solution that works for a container-bound script with Google Sheets without HTML? I would like to adapt this to just Google Sheets.

The following is the google script (.gs) server-side code from the tutorial:

```
    var APIKey = 'xxxx';

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Main').evaluate();
}

function buildJSONRequestImgUrl(imgUrl) {
  return JSON.stringify({
    requests: [{
      image: {
        source: {
          imageUri: imgUrl
        }
      },
      features: [{
        type: "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION",
        maxResults: 1
      }]
    }]
  });
}


function makeRequest(imgUrl) {
  // Make a POST request to Vision API with a JSON payload.      
  var visionApiUrl = 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' +
    APIKey;
  var JSON_REQ = buildJSONRequestImgUrl(imgUrl);
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON_REQ
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(visionApiUrl, options);
  return response.getContentText();
}
```

The following is the html client-side code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <base target="_top">
      <script>
         function callVisionAPI(){
           var status = document.getElementById('status'); 
           var imgUrl = document.getElementById('imgUrl');
           status.innerHTML = "<b>Calling VISION API with imgUrl: </b>" + imgUrl.value;
           console.log("Calling Vision API w/ imgUrl: " + imgUrl.value);
           google.script.run
             .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
               status.innerHtml = 'Error calling server function makeRequest: ' + error;
             })
             .withSuccessHandler(function(result){
             console.log('Raw response from Vision API: ' + result);
               var JResp =  JSON.parse(result); 
               showResponse(JResp, imgUrl.value);
           }).makeRequest(imgUrl.value);  
         }
         
         
         function showResponse(JSON, imgUrl){
           var status = document.getElementById('status');
           var imgTag = document.getElementById('ImgTag');
           if (typeof(JSON['responses'][0]['textAnnotations']) != "undefined"){
             var textResp = JSON['responses'][0]['textAnnotations'][0];
             var description = textResp["description"];
             var locale = textResp['locale'];    
             status.innerHTML = '<b>Converted Text:</b> ' + description;
             imgTag.src = imgUrl;      
           } else
             status.innerHTML = 'Unable to analyze text. Try an image with better contrast.';
         }
             
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Google Cloud Vision API & G Suite</h2>
      <h3>Document Text Detection (OCR)</h3>
      <div>
         <input id="imgUrl" type="text" placeholder="http://<<URL of image>>" size="80"/>
         <button onClick="callVisionAPI()">Call Vision API</button>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div>
         <image id="ImgTag" height="400" width="600"/>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div id="status"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```